# AngularJs Calling controller function from directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which creates dynamic datas.I try to run context menu when right click it should go to controller function to run but i can't run function because it can't find controller function from directive.

**My Controller:**

```
myapp.controller("myController", ['$scope',
function ($scope)
{
  $scope.test=function(){return $scope.Options = [
        ['test']
        ];
        }
   ........
```

**My Directive:**

```
 myapp.directive('mydirective', [
    '$timeout', function ($timeout) {
        return {

            restrict: 'E',
            template: "<a ng-context-menu='test()'>Click Right</a>",
        .................
```

How can i call the controller function from dynamically created data?

Comment: Set the `controller` field on your directive to `myController`.

Comment: @user4773604 AngularJS documentation – https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate

Comment: It works but I have 3 different controller ,i can't set a specific controller name ,it should be dynamic

Comment: I would argue that this is indicative of bad design. Each directive should be a well defined component - having the possibility of 3 mutations does not seem well defined to me. I did check to see if there was a `controllerFactory` option but there does not seem to be one. If you absolutely must do this, you must inject `$controller` into a function on the `controller` field and return a controller that way. But please, do not do this.

Comment: Is it possible such as;  template: "<a  mycontroller  ng-context-menu='test()'>Click Right</a>"